# Coded UI throws "specified cast is not valid" exception when running browser.ExecuteScript

Tags: javascript, coded-ui-tests

When I was trying executing javascript in coded UI test with the simple example:

```
BrowserWindow browserWindow = BrowserWindow.Launch("http://www.bing.com");
browserWindow.ExecuteScript("alert('Hello World')");
```

I got this error:

```
Specified cast is not valid.
```

My testing environment is: Visual studio 2013 ultimate with update 4
                           IE11

Could this be because of IE version or I missed some setting. Thanks for your help!

Comment: is your test able to launch browser?

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, BrowserWindow.Launch expects a Uri parameter:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.bing.com");
BrowserWindow browserWindow = BrowserWindow.Launch(uri);
```